# Посчитать проценты в списке

Tags: python, list

Как проверить на сколько следующее число больше в процентах от предыдущего?

```
for k in a:
```

Дано:

```
a =

[171,
 53,
 1072,
 56]
```

Результат в %:

```
a =

[0,
 -69.01,
 2002.64,
 -94.88]
```

Comment: оооо, это я умею

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [171, 53, 1072, 56]
print([0] + [round(a[i] / a[i-1] * 100, 2) - 100 for i in range(1, len(a))])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [171, 53, 1072, 56]
res = [0]

for a, b in zip(a, a[1:]):
    res.append(round(b / a * 100, 2) - 100)

print(res)
```

Comment: @Valent зачем?.

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз разница нужна, то так:

```
a = [171, 53, 1072, 56]
print([0] + [round((y-x) / x * 100, 2) for x,y in zip(a, a[1:])])
```

Вывод:

```
[0, -69.01, 1922.64, -94.78]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```py
a = [171, 53, 1072, 56]

for n, i in enumerate(a):
    if n == 0: # Для первого[0] элемента
        print(0)
        continue 
    s = ((i-a[n-1])/a[n-1]*100)
    print(round(s, 2))
```

На выходе получите:

```
0
-69.01
1922.64
-94.78
```